# Transparent corner in rectangle, Android

Tags: android, xml, shapes

I'm trying to achieve the following effect using XML:

[image: Goal]

The idea is to generate a rectangle, which has a transparent corner (the top left one indicating the days left, and the bottom right one indicating the amount of credits).

What I've achieved is the following using a layer-list:

[image: Current result]

As you can see there's a white background, which I'd like for it to be transparent. The problem is, that if I use transparent as color, I end up with a normal rectangle.

Here's the XML I've been using:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <size android:width="100dp" android:height="100dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@color/mission_time_left"/>
    </shape>

</item>
<item>
    <rotate android:fromDegrees="-45" android:pivotX="0%" android:pivotY="100%" android:toDegrees="-45">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:width="100dp" android:height="100dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

Any help would be appreciated on how to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the right bottom triangle with transparent corner, add it to normal rectangle, for upper corner change pivots 0 to 100 and 100 to 0

```
     <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
            <item>
                <rotate
                    android:fromDegrees="45"
                    android:toDegrees="45"
                    android:pivotX="0%"
                android:pivotY="100%" >
                <shape
                    android:shape="rectangle" >
                    <stroke android:color="@color/transparent" android:width="10dp"/>
                    <solid
                        android:color="@color/red_busket_price" />
                </shape>
            </rotate>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Alexander. I'm not quite sure how to add the xml you suggest to a rectangle. Could you please give an example?

Comment: make two image views, in one triangle, in another rectangle and place then together